# Usinge flow from files list in grep --include

Tags: variables, grep, include

Hello I want use flow of files list as grep parameter include

Please tell me how to fix problem (please don't suggest me use loop like for it sloweed this script).

```
grep -rl --include={$(sed 's/\ /,/g' <<< $(basename -a $(grep -Eo 'ht+ps*:/+[[:graph:]]+' /path/to/fileslist)))} '' /path/for/search

echo $?
1
or
a=$(sed 's/\ /,/g' <<< $(basename -a $(grep -Eo 'ht+ps*:/+[[:graph:]]+' /path/to/fileslist)))
grep -rl --include={$a} '' /path/for/search

echo $?
1

but when I use it in explicitly (fileslist delimited by ,) it work properly
grep -rl --include={file1.ext,file2.ext,...,fileN.ext} '' /media/mint/
echo $?
0
```

Comment: if I understand what you are *trying* to do, this is either *really* slick, or totally bogus. Not sure which just yet. :)

Comment: Use `find` to **find** files, not `grep -r`, to make your life easier.

Comment: Regarding "please don't suggest me use loop like for it sloweed this script" - until you get a script that works, don't try to compare how fast it executes against anything else as anyone can write a script that's blistering fast as long as it doesn't have to work. Also, you can write a loop that's slow but you can also write a loop that's fast so having found one loop to be slow doesn't mean all loops are slow.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Why are you including an empty regex pattern?
That's going to match the empty in front of the first character, if there is a first character, though I think it will skip completely empty files.

Are you trying to use `grep` when you really should probably be using `find`?

Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

It looks to me like what you really want is:

```
lst=( $(basename -a $( grep -Eo 'ht+ps*:/+[[:graph:]]+' /path/to/fileslist ) ) )
find /path/for/search -name $( sed 's/ / -o -name /g' <<< "${lst[@]}" ) -type f
```

or perhaps even just

```
shopt -s extglob
ls /path/for/search**/+($(IFS=\|; echo "${lst[*]}"))
```

If you *meant* to skip the empty files, `find` has a built-in test for that too.

```
find /path/for/search ! -empty -a \( -name $( sed 's/ / -o -name /g' <<< "${lst[@]}" ) \) -type f
```

...but to answer the question you *asked*...

---

You can't build and execute that syntax dynamically that way.
The `{x,y}` structure doesn't interpolate its own *syntax*.
The commas can't be part of the *values*.

```
$: a=2; b=4; ls {$a,$b}.txt # works; comma still literal
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 29 Dec 22 09:35 2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 29 Dec 22 09:35 4.txt
$: x="2,4"; ls {$x}.txt     # comma here is value, not syntax
ls: cannot access '{2,4}.txt': No such file or directory
```

It will need at least one step of abstraction, so that the parser sees the pattern *syntax* as a literal, not part of the value set.

Assuming this, your code to construct the pattern, is correct,

```
a=$(sed 's/ /,/g' <<< $(basename -a $(grep -Eo 'ht+ps*:/+[[:graph:]]+' /path/to/fileslist)))
```

you *could* use an `eval`.

```
eval "grep -rl --include={$a} '' /path/for/search"
```

That parses the strings, *then* passes the literal resultys to the `eval` so that it works.

I generally dislike `eval`, and sometimes instead will write a small dynamically generated code file, then source it, though it isn't really any faster or safer.

```
echo "grep -rl --include={$a} '' /path/for/search" > tmpfile
. tmpfile
```

But again, this looks like you are just using `grep`'s `--include` and `--recursive` functions with an empty regex to list non-empty files. If so, then as stated above: use `find`.